# Repository - Insert method

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I'am using typeorm https://typeorm.io and I was trying to insert a new record on my `users` table in a mysql database.

I have this entity.

```
export interface UserEntity {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  confirmedSignUp: boolean;
  createdAt: string;
}

export const User = new EntitySchema<UserEntity>({
  name: "users",
  columns: {
    id: {
      type: "integer",
      primary: true,
      generated: true
    },
    email: {
      type: "varchar",
      unique: true,
      length: 150,
      nullable: false
    },
    password: {
      type: "varchar",
      length: 80,
      nullable: false,
      
    },
    confirmedSignUp: {
      type: "boolean",
      default: false
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: "timestamp",
      default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    }
  }
})
```

As you can see, fields `password` and `email` are required for mysql because they have `nullable: false`. But when I try to insert a new record with `insert` method, `password` and `email` fields are optional. As docs say, insert method converts all keys from entity on its optional form with that `QueryDeepPartialEntity`.

http://typeorm-doc.exceptionfound.com/classes/repository.html#insert

Can someone explain me this behavior when I want to insert a new record ?. Shouldn't be Non-nullable fields required (in my case password and email) ?

Thanks!